# how to change state and get data select options and show data in options

Tags: reactjs

I want to click on the option to show the data in the second select but the problem is that the previous information is in the select options

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6jhwbe

this is my states

```
            StateID,
            CityID,
```

this is my onChange Methode

```
handleChangeStateID(event){
    this.setState({StateID: event.target.value});
    this.handleRequestCities();
}
handleChangeCityID(event){
    this.setState({CityID: event.target.value});
}
```

this is my axios methodes

```
handleRequestState(){
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://www.simkhan.ir/webapi/api/common/getallstate',
    })
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                states: response.data
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

handleRequestCities(){
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://www.simkhan.ir/webapi/api/common/getallcitybyStateID',
        data : {
            StateID: this.state.StateID
        },
    })
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                Cities: response.data
            });
            console.log(this.state.Cities)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}


componentDidMount() {
    this.handleRequestState();
}
```

and this is my select opthions

```
                                        <div className="col-12 col-md-6">
                                            <label>
                                                استان
                                                <select value={this.state.StateID} onChange={this.handleChangeStateID.bind(this)}>
                                                    {
                                                        this.state.states === undefined
                                                        ?
                                                            (
                                                                <div></div>
                                                            )
                                                            :
                                                            (
                                                                this.state.states.map( (states, index) => <option key={index} value={states.StateID}>{states.StateName}</option> )
                                                            )

                                                    }
                                                </select>
                                            </label>


                                        </div>

                                        <div className="col-12 col-md-6">


                                            {
                                                this.state.Cities === undefined
                                                    ?
                                                    (
                                                        <div></div>
                                                    )
                                                    :
                                                    this.state.Cities === null
                                                    ?
                                                        (
                                                            <div></div>
                                                        )
                                                        :
                                                        this.state.Cities.length === 1
                                                            ?
                                                            (
                                                                <div></div>
                                                            )
                                                    :
                                                    (
                                                        <label>
                                                            شهراستان
                                                            <select value={this.state.Cities} onChange={this.handleChangeCityID.bind(this)}>
                                                                {this.state.Cities.map( (Cities, index) => <option key={index} value={Cities.CityID}>{Cities.CityName}</option> )}
                                                            </select>
                                                        </label>
                                                    )
                                            }



                                        </div>
```

I want the option from the first select to be filled in immediately from the second select and also display their StateId and CityID values to api information

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6jhwbe

Comment: if you can put your code in codepen or some website like that people can help better, thanks

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6jhwbe